# Working with stdin

Tags: c, console, stdin

So I have to implement a program that works with a text file (*.txt*), which has been put to stdin like that: `./program [argumets] <textfile.txt` without using such functions as fopen, fscanf, malloc, etc. and I have no idea how to do that. I need to work with characters in that text file (print them to screen, print max/min value, print sum, etc.), NOT with the file itself, so, maybe anyone got a hint? Thank you.

Comment: the basic file handling function will help you.. `open()`

Comment: A [good reference might be helpfull](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io)?

Comment: You don't have to do anything special to get from stdin. It's automatically opened for you, you can just read from it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875650/multi-line-stdin-c/12875715

Comment: You have to remember that `stdin` is a normal file stream just as the ones opened by `fopen`. Start by trying to use e.g. `fscanf` or similar functions with `stdin` and you can then easily switch that out to a file opened by `fopen` instead.

Comment: @Barmar this is what I need, but I don't get the way to implement it. Is file from stdin stored in some variable? Or what is the way to manipulate with characters in that text file?

Comment: Yes, the variable is named `stdin`. It's defined automatically by `<stdio.h>`. Doesn't your textbook explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Reading from text file like this as nearly identical to reading from keyboard. So much so that without doing some special tricks, your program has no way to know if input comes from keyboarad or from file.

When you do need to use a function which requires a file, there is `stdin`, which is so called "file pointer", and has type `FILE*`, same as returned by `fopen`.  File pointer is accepted by functions likes `fscanf` (but you can just call `scanf` then) and `fgets` (do *NOT* use `gets`, it's fatally broken, and finally removed from C11 standard).

If you need to use functions which take file descriptor, which is integer, and returned for example by `open` call, and accepted by functions like `read`, then the file descriptor number for standard input is 0, but you should usually use the `STDIN_FILENO` constant. And, do not mix reading from file descriptor (unbuffered), and reading from `FILE*` (buffered), because buffering will mess up the data you get. Using `FILE*` is probably better for most applications.

To make this more concrete, you can develop your program so, that instead of using `<` to redirect the input file, you can open the input file in editor, copy it to clipboard, run your application in a terminal, and paste input file as text to the terminal.